# Photoshopped image background all white

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, photoshop

I'm have two images which are both the same, one of which I edited the opacity to 90% in photoshop. My original image renders fine while my edited image(s) render all white. I changed nothing in the code except the actual file itself. Maybe somebody could shed some light here. Thanks

Working CSS

```
#home-header {
background-image: url(firepit2.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
height: 841px;
display: block;
}
```

Non working CSS

```
#home-header {
background-image: url(firepit2.psd);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
height: 841px;
display: block;
}
```

I even tried saving the new file as a jpg to see if the issue was with the psd extension and it still did not work. Maybe I need to convert it?

Comment: `.psd` is not a valid format for image, it's a photoshop extension, which has nothing to do with image

Comment: I thought that might be it but when I saved it to jpg it did the same thing. Do I need to convert the psd via a file converter to jpg maybe?

Comment: Photoshop should offer a converter of its own. Try using that.

Comment: You can save as `.jpg`, `.png` or any other valid image format straight from photoshop

Comment: Code doesn't change the background image of the source art. You need to save as a transparent image (png is best).

Comment: Ok. I'll give it a try. I know photoshop is a great app but I hate using it.

Comment: also save png file in the same directory of css or edit "url" attribute

Comment: With regards to the neg votes I'm a bit perplexed as it was a legitimate issue in which I failed to find a straight answer elsewhere. In that context, I would assume the solution here would be helpful to others in the future so if thats a negative thing then call me confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the image as png if it has a transparency

Comment: While I appreciate all answers and comments, this particular answer was the most relevant with what worked for me at the moment. I changed opacity to 80% in PS and then saved as a copy to PNG. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you want a show a image no background color, you can use format png, or other option for solve for example if you want change the color for your picture in focus, you can use javascript simple code.

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl("image.png"); ?>" onmouseover="this.style.opacity=0.8" onmouseout="this.style.opacity=1" />
```

Comment: Whereabouts would you recommend putting this code CVIDAL? Html, body? Thanks for the input.

Comment: I'm still a newbie in general but especially with JS.